# Localization using Angular CLI with i18n results in error regarding MissingTranslationStrategy

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I am trying to execute this command from:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p ./Root --i18nFile=./Root/Localization/Resources.es.xlf --locale=es --i18nFormat=xlf --missingTranslation=warning
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'MissingTranslationStrategy' of undefined
    at getAotCompilerOptions (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:611:45)
    at AngularCompilerProgram._createCompiler (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:390:26)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.get [as hostAdapter] (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:319:22)
    at AngularCompilerProgram._createProgramWithBasicStubs (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:431:72)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.initSync (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:373:27)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.get [as tsProgram] (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:349:22)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.getTsOptionDiagnostics (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:104:20)
    at defaultGatherDiagnostics (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\perform_compile.js:181:34)
    at Object.performCompilation (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\perform_compile.js:138:51)
    at main (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:29:42)
```

It seems like `core` is undefined in `compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.ts`.

```
import { ..., core, ... } from '@angular/compiler';

function getAotCompilerOptions(options: CompilerOptions): AotCompilerOptions {
    let missingTranslation = core.MissingTranslationStrategy.Warning;
    ...
}
```

Hopefully someone knows or have experienced the same and are able to help.

Thanks in advance.